# Develop a kid's photographic memory

Tags: development

I've been searching this topic on internet but all of them were related to adults, but I would like to incentivete, estimulate my kid photographic memory, I found this skill very useful for other people when I was in college.
My kid is a toddler, so she doesn't read yet.

Comment: You have a child who *has* a eidetic memory?  Or you want to help your child develop one?  I think the latter is impossible - you either have an eidetic memory or you don't.  You can develop a *better* memory, but not an eidetic one .

Comment: yep, you born with eidetic memory, but my questions is how to deveop a better memory, in ohter words :)

Comment: You might want to edit your post then to make that more clear.

Comment: I've placed this on hold until you can clarify if your son has this capacity already or not, because that greatly affects the answers that can be given. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Photogenic memory is USELESS for life.  You just turned your son into a really expensive cell phone.  I'm in IT, and my general advice is, don't make a career out of something easily done with technology, because you'll be easily replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How old is your son? Kids should develop their memory by playing little games like memory. A good thing what I do with my kid is to read a small story with him and ask him one day later some stuff about the story(plot, characters). Another good thing would be small computer games. Kids love computers! BE AWARE not every game is good!

Keep in mind a kid is a kid and they can't always do what you want them to do. Some kids have awesome memory others don't but that's what makes us unique.